# executing Intermediate function without calling final function forEach()

Tags: java, lambda

My code reads in `people.txt`, constructs many person objects and adds them to a persons list. 
But if I remove the forEach, stream.map()  function is not executed as it is an intermediate function hence I need forEach or any other final function.

However, I dont want any Consumer lambda to be executed in forEach function (a print statement in this case). How do I do that?

My main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Person> persons=new ArrayList<>();

    try(
            BufferedReader reader=
                new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                                Main.class.getResourceAsStream("people.txt")));

        Stream<String> stream=reader.lines();

    ){

            stream.map(line->{
                String[] s=line.split(" ");
                Person p=new Person(
                        s[0].trim(),
                        Integer.parseInt(s[1]),
                        s[2].trim()
                );
                persons.add(p);
                return p;
            }).forEach(System.out::print);

    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: The stream API isn't meant to be used with functions that have side effects. Your map lambda adds stuff to a list as a side effect. The answers below show how map is meant to be used

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Person> persons = stream.map(line->{
        String[] s=line.split(" ");
        Person p=new Person(
                s[0].trim(),
                Integer.parseInt(s[1]),
                s[2].trim()
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to use custom list than `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(persons))`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to map anything if you are not going to collect it.
By adding them to list you are already consuming them so you can do something like :

```
stream.forEach(line->{
            String[] s=line.split(" ");
            Person p=new Person(
                    s[0].trim(),
                    Integer.parseInt(s[1]),
                    s[2].trim()
            );
            persons.add(p);
        })
```

This way you will still fill the list.
Also, what you can do is

```
stream.map(line->{
            String[] s=line.split(" ");
            Person p=new Person(
                    s[0].trim(),
                    Integer.parseInt(s[1]),
                    s[2].trim()
            );
            return p;
        }).forEach(persons::add);
```

Also, you shouldn't do any side-effects in your map function, which adding something to list is. map() should be used only for mapping stuff to stream, adding something to list is way of consuming it. Also you can do following if this is the only place where you add stuff to persons list:

```
persons = stream.map(line->{
        String[] s=line.split(" ");
        Person p=new Person(
                s[0].trim(),
                Integer.parseInt(s[1]),
                s[2].trim()
        );
        return p;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

More compact solution using the only Stream API:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                Main.class.getResourceAsStream("people.txt")))) {
            List<Person> peoples = reader.lines()
                    .map(line -> line.split(" "))
                    .map(tuple -> new Person(
                            tuple[0].trim(),
                            Integer.parseInt(tuple[1]),
                            tuple[2].trim()
                    ))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            peoples.forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```